# Cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection'

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to train TF2 for object detection. When I run model_main_tf2.py, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_venv\trained_models\model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection' (c:\Python_venv\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\__init__.py)
```

How do I install model_lib_v2?

I tried reinstalling TF and reinstalling TensorFlow-object-detection-API but no luck. I went all over the internet looking for answers.

I found:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7920
But they don't say how to install model_lib_v2

Unfortunately I cannot use TF1, the goal is to use TF2.

Answer (score 7):

see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

## Python Package Installation
cd models/research
### Compile protos.

protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
### Install TensorFlow Object Detection API.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python3 -m pip install --user --use-feature=2020-resolver .
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have 
some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the 
target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: It would be great if you could add some explanation too instead of a simple "see <linkk>"

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 , the respectively [link](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tf-models-install)

Comment: what models branch are you using? I found research\object_detection for tf 2.3.0 but there is no object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py
I want to us tf 2.5 but there is no object_detection folder

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to just go to line 32 in "C:\Python_venv\trained_models\model_main_tf2.py" and remove "from object_detection", since you are already inside the package.

replace:

"from object_detection import model_lib_v2"

by:

"import model_lib_v2"