# ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tf2 to do object detection training, but in the stage to run model_main_tf2.py, I face this error:

```
2021-05-16 04:57:52.445583: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/RealTimeObjectDetection/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/__init__.py)
```

May I know how to solve this? I already try with [ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' I am use Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304716/importerror-cannot-import-name-model-lib-v2-i-am-use-colab)  and [cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296894/cannot-import-name-model-lib-v2-from-object-detection)...I also done download TF models, keep in the file, no error while running protoc. Thank you :)

Comment: Try the workaround mentioned [here](http://www.databloom.com/2021/02/20/importerror-cannot-import-name-model_lib_v2-fromobject_detectioncusersasusappdataroamingpythonpython38site-packagesobject_detection__init__-py/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually I solve the problem with changing the new GPU run time, restart the process and it works ! I think the problem might be I change the tensor flow version accidentally  or I forget to use GPU while runing the process.