# 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection' can not be imported

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to train a model for object detection and while performing so I came across this error. I tried resolving it but seems like solution is not available on internet.

The whole file:

```
from absl import flags
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
from object_detection import model_lib_v2

flags.DEFINE_string('pipeline_config_path', None, 'Path to pipeline config '
                    'file.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_train_steps', None, 'Number of train steps.')
flags.DEFINE_bool('eval_on_train_data', False, 'Enable evaluating on train '
                  'data (only supported in distributed training).')
flags.DEFINE_integer('sample_1_of_n_eval_examples', None, 'Will sample one of '
                     'every n eval input examples, where n is provided.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples', 5, 'Will sample '
                     'one of every n train input examples for evaluation, '
                     'where n is provided. This is only used if '
                     '`eval_training_data` is True.')
flags.DEFINE_string(
    'model_dir', None, 'Path to output model directory '
                       'where event and checkpoint files will be written.')
flags.DEFINE_string(
    'checkpoint_dir', None, 'Path to directory holding a checkpoint.  If '
    '`checkpoint_dir` is provided, this binary operates in eval-only mode, '
    'writing resulting metrics to `model_dir`.')

flags.DEFINE_integer('eval_timeout', 3600, 'Number of seconds to wait for an'
                     'evaluation checkpoint before exiting.')

flags.DEFINE_bool('use_tpu', False, 'Whether the job is executing on a TPU.')
flags.DEFINE_string(
    'tpu_name',
    default=None,
    help='Name of the Cloud TPU for Cluster Resolvers.')
flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'num_workers', 1, 'When num_workers > 1, training uses '
    'MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy. When num_workers = 1 it uses '
    'MirroredStrategy.')
flags.DEFINE_integer(
    'checkpoint_every_n', 1000, 'Integer defining how often we checkpoint.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('record_summaries', True,
                     ('Whether or not to record summaries defined by the model'
                      ' or the training pipeline. This does not impact the'
                      ' summaries of the loss values which are always'
                      ' recorded.'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot import name 'model\_lib\_v2' from 'object\_detection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296894/cannot-import-name-model-lib-v2-from-object-detection)

Comment: No. All of the measures doesn't help!

Comment: Answer: Just searched the file model_lib_v2 and added it inside tensorflow folder with all other python file and libraries.