# ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

i ran into this issue when i was executing the command of training tensorflow object detection model, i have tried to fix it by upgrading tensorflow version to 2.0, according to this stack overflow post [Cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296894/cannot-import-name-model-lib-v2-from-object-detection) but it doesnt work successfully, the error still persist, does anyone knows a fix to this issue, below contains the error when im running the code

[image]

i tried to follow the tensorflow documentation and upgrade the tensorflow version in jupyter notebook, but when i rerun the command in picture 1 above, the error still persist

[image]

[image]